# Should i have to store entire product information in order table in order to remove this conflict?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, e-commerce

I am developing an ecommerce website. I have created the following tables.

```
products
--------
id
name
price

orders
------
id
customer_id
billing_name
billing_address
shipping_name
shipping_address


ordered_products
----------------
id
product_id
order_id
```

I am storing the customer id and product id in orders, ordered_products respectively. I am displaying the order history from the above tables after joining.

After some orders I change the product price in product table. This price change is also reflecting the order history.
Say for example product price was $10.00 when an user bought the product in past. When I update the product price $20.00 . It is showing $20.00 in order history instead of $10.00.

What should I do ?

Should i have to store entire product information in order table in order to remove this conflict?

Comment: What you have is called a slowly changing dimension.  A good place to start on understanding what to do is the Wikipedia page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension.

Comment: You need 1) some way to track changes to your product entry table, period (Even for something as trivial as the color!), and 2) some way to deal with customers getting special deals.  That's right, you can't forget that sometimes you want to charge somebody $1 for that $150 part!  IOW, you probably want to add a `sellPrice` to `ordered_products`, besides tracking normal price changes.  (And note that this is different from providing credits as part of payments...)  Just wait 'til you get to taxes, that's even more fun!